# Compare and insert count number of elements in columns into table in perl

Tags: perl, unix

I'm working in with two large data sets (300 x 500,000) and I've got a matrix with 0,1, 2 and NA values in both data, and I would like to compare these files and count the number are matching in both files by every row and insert the results into the a output table results.

```
File 1

2    1    0
0    1    1
1    0    NA

File 2

2    1    0
Na   1    1
1    NA   0
```

How can I compare count of match values in every row and the total sum?

Answer (score 0):

I've interpreted what you mean by "total" and the count of matching lines is just dumped but this does what you asked for and you should be able to adopt it to your exact spec

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
# open files with error checking
open(my $f1,"file1") || die "$! file1";
open(my $f2,"file2") || die "$! file2";

#hash to store count of similar rows in
my %match_count=();
#total sum
my $total=0;

#read line from each file, lower case it to ignore Na NA difference and
#chomp to remove \n so this isn't stored 
while(my $l1=lc(<$f1>)) {
    my $l2 = lc(<$f2>);
    chomp($l1);
    chomp($l2);
    #see if lines are the same
    if ($l1 eq $l2) {
        #increment counter for this line
        $match_count{$l1}++;
        #find sum of row and add to total
        my ($first,$second,$third) = split(/\s/,$l1);
        $total += $first+$second+$third;
    }
}

print "sum total of matches = $total\n";
print Dumper(\%match_count);
```

Comment: The total that match in two files as a table with total about the elements inside the two files as 0, 1, 2. The NA I don't wanna check.

Comment: @user2288980 if you are looking for more help then "NA I don't wanna check" doesn't add anything to the requirements